# Setting up Debugger with C++ makefile project in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, makefile, gdb

I have a C++ project which i've been working on for a while. I decided to import it into eclipse mainly for code-completion/parsing and visual-debugging.
The project uses a makefile, and g++ compiler.
The relevant flags i pass to g++ are:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS = -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -rdynamic -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -DDEBUG -std=c++11

LIB_FLAGS = -lglfw -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lpthread -lXxf86vm ./Libraries/libpng/built/libpng14.a -lz
```

I can debug the executable from the command line just fine. But when i try to set up a debug configuration in eclipse it seems to always break in a certain _dl_debug_state() with no symbols available (regardless of whether or not i have any breakpoints set)

When i turn on verbose logging i think i see it is in a shared library: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

I tried importing just the executable into a debug configuration, and that had the same result.

I read other questions in here and other forums which seemed to deal with the same issue, but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, fixed it.
In the Debug-configuration, under the "Debugger" tab, there is a "Shared Libraries" sub-tab. Unchecking "Load shared library symbols automatically" helped.

Basically, i could see in the verbose output that it was doing some things with "auto-solib-add" and "stop-on-solib-event" , but the sub-tab was kind of hidden and i didn't find it quickly enough in my meddling.